# Google Cloud Workflows - Concurrent executions limit

Tags: google-workflows

For "Concurrent executions", in the list of the "Request limits" of Workflows' quotas docs, there is a limit of "100 executions".

> "Concurrent executions - The maximum number of active (started and not
> yet completed) workflow executions per project:   100 executions"

https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas

What does this limit really means, for example if a workflow execution is waiting for a HTTP callback, then it is "started and not yet completed". In this case this limit of 100 executions being in this waiting state seems to me very few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding that's correct. An execution is a single run of the logic contained in a workflow's definition. All workflow executions are independent and they may concur at the same time depending on the design of the workflow and how is trigger. Important for that reason to consider carefully the sleep and retry logics of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be the case, but a limit of 100 "started and not yet completed" executions is still unbelievable few for me in a real-world scenario, ie. in a 1000 concurrent sessions application. For examlpe one of the use cases on Workflows' official site talks about "Automation: low-latency shipment processing" ([link](https://cloud.google.com/workflows#section-6)).  What if a step takes a bit longer than expected?

Comment: Or another use case example: "human validation of automated translation". [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/introducing-workflows-callbacks) How can this work with this very low (100) limitation of concurrent executions?

Comment: I have been able to inform myself that the goal of Google is to remove the concurrent executions limit eventually, perhaps replacing it with some throttling on steps executed per second. For now, they are in the process of raising the limit to 1000.