# Does Cloud Workflows executions really fail when the Failed status reaches 2000?

Tags: quota, google-workflows

I have a question about "Concurrent executions" in the following document.
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas?hl=en#request_limit

I would like to leave execution in a failed state or delete failed execution.

But I read the document and it reads as follows:

- Unable to delete execution.
- Once the failed status has accumulated to 2000, the execution can no longer be created.

I would first like to confirm that this perception is correct.

Does every workflow executions have to be Success?

I read the document
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/quotas?hl=en#request_limit
[Google Cloud Workflows - Concurrent executions limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539297/google-cloud-workflows-concurrent-executions-limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrent executions only counts executions that have not yet completed or failed. Executions in a failed state are not counted, so you are fine to leave them (which is usually what you want for inspecting and processing later).